# How to build and install the latest nightly Firefox OS on Alcatel One Touch Fire?

Tags: build, firefox-os, b2g

I want to upgrade Firefox OS 1.1 on my Alcatel One Touch Fire to the master branch (the latest revision). After having read the [Mozilla Wiki](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Building_and_installing_Firefox_OS), I cloned the B2G repository, built it for the *hamachi* target by typing:

```
./config.sh hamachi && ./build.sh
```

(There are even [prebuilt images](http://b2g.vegnux.org.ve))

Now is the hardest part, since Alcatel phones are not rooted and seems to have a locked bootloader.

The docs say that I should flash the device by typing:

```
./flash.sh
```

But all I get are these errors:

```
   adbd cannot run as root in production builds
   remount failed: Operation not permitted
   push: /home/user/B2G/objdir-gecko/dist/b2g/dictionaries/en-US.aff -> /system/b2g/dictionaries/en-US.aff
   failed to copy '/home/user/B2G/objdir-gecko/dist/b2g/dictionaries/en-US.aff' to '/system/b2g/dictionaries/en-US.aff': Read-only file system
```

Could anybody write an simple step-by-step tutorial (easier than [this](http://k.japko.eu/alcatel-otf-hackers-guide-1.html)) on how to install the latest Firefox OS to a stock Alcatel One Touch Fire?

Comment: all firefox OS phones are a dead platform. why mozilla keep insisting on the error? nobody knows. it probably give them revenue somehow. anyway, all the devs agree that those phones are all dead ends. do not generate more garbage on earth. avoid all and any mozilla firefox os phones. use only the emulator and let devs use android phones for now.

Comment: @gcb False. Definitely not all devs think FxOS is a dead end. It is gaining popularity throughout Asia and South America and it is the only platform being fully open source.

Comment: i meant firefox OS _phones_. not the OS itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from [Mozilla guide on flashing phones](https://etherpad.mozilla.org/flashing-phones) related to Hamachi (Alcatel One Touch Fire):

> - Best build for Hamachi: moz-central Use your LDAP to go here: https://pvtbuilds.mozilla.org/pvt/mozilla.org/b2g_ril/latest-hamachi-mozilla-central/
>     And then run this script command line: fullflash_gecko_ril_gaia.sh You
>     may need to preface this with ./ but it should just run upon your
>     hitting enter. DON'T run ./flash.sh. THIS CAN BRICK YOUR HAMACHI :( -
>     GB
> - What is my order of operations from the beginning?
>     FOR ALL DEVICES...   AFTER you have installed ADB, Git, and Xcode, you should:
>
>   1. Connect your device to your machine via USB. You're SURE it's plugged in? OK then...
>   2. Get your build with your LDAP credentials (from moz-central): Buri: Need from Naoki Hamachi:
>        https://pvtbuilds.mozilla.org/pvt/mozilla.org/b2g_ril/latest-hamachi-mozilla-central/
>   3. Run this script: fullflash_gecko_ril_gaia.sh
>   4. Download gaia from github (it's easier than the command line as you avoid a pull request) at: https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia Along
>        the right hand side there is an option to "Download ZIP." Unpack that
>        into a folder, open Terminal and "cd" (ask Stephany or Francis if you
>        need help with this) into the folder (i.e. wherever you unpacked your
>        zip file). Run "make reset-gaia".
>   5. You should see... a whole bunch of stuff scrolling by on the command line and your device should reboot. If your device does NOT
>        reboot, try ADB reboot.

Comment: The Hamachi builds have not been built by the Mozilla infrastructure for a while. The directory is now empty.

Answer (score 2):

I guess first we can check if the phone itself is rooted.
You could try,

```
$ adb shell
```

And if shows,

```
root@android:/ #
```

Then I think the phone is rooted, and you can flash your phone with `./flash.sh`.

If it is not rooted, I think the [link](http://k.japko.eu/alcatel-otf-hackers-guide-1.html) you mentioned has provided the steps to create a new boot.img so that you could root the phone.